# What's the difference between 지금 and 이제?

Tags: meaning

They both seem to mean `now` or `right now` and im struggling to figure out when I would use one or the other. Until now I have always used `지금`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 지금

`지금` = `Now` / `Right now`.

### 이제

`이제` is a lot different word from `지금`, basically meaning `Since now and on...`. It is said when you're about to do something from now on, or you barely made it done by now.

Examples:

> 이제(부터) 달라질 것이다.

- (From now on) I'll be changing.

> 이제(야) 도착했다.

- I've just/finally arrived. (It took me so long to get here.)